# Keyboard partially stops working while playing games

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I've recently got back into playing some PC games, however yesterday I started experiencing some weird problems. Whenever I'm inside a game, the keyboard either chooses not to work at all, or it registers keypresses very rarely. I have no idea why this happens.

I can type completely normally outside of games, and have tried using another keyboard to no avail. This indicates a software problem somewhere, but I have no idea how this could have happened or how I could fix it.

I've seen various bits on the internet of people with similar/the same problems however none are conclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that re-installing Java fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First try to replace keybord - if it works it means that your keyboard is dead.
If it fails we will look for a cause of this problem.